# Probability with Christmas presents

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem about Christmas presents. We are 25 friend and we want to do a present each other secretly. Which is the probability that person A does a present to a person B and a person B do a present to a person A? The probability increase or decrease if we are 30 or more? I know that it's quite easy but I can't find the solution :')

Comment: We need more information : What exactly is meant with "secretely" ? Do you want the probability that there is at least one pair giving a present each other ? Or anything else ?

Comment: With "secretly" I mean that when you extract the name of the person who you have to do a present no-one see it. Yes I basically want that probability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $!25$ equiprobable outcomes and under the condition that *fixed pair* A and B give to eachother there are $!23$ favorable outcomes.

So the probability on this is:$$\frac{!23}{!25}$$

Also have a look at [derangements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

For another example treating more aspects see [here](https://www.quora.com/Six-people-draw-lots-to-buy-gifts-for-each-other-What-is-the-probability-that-2-people-pick-each-other-its-not-possible-to-pick-yourself/answer/Henk-Brozius?ch=10&oid=404140707&share=1988e4be&srid=uw8zW&target_type=answer).